# Location of Templates on Netbeans 7.2 MacOSX 10.8.2

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-7.2

Where are the template files created under Tools > Templates located on MacOSX?

As other posts suggested I've checked ~/.netbeans/[version]/config/Templates, but I can only find templates for an older version (7.1.1) here, and not for the 7.2 installed.

the folder ~/.netbeans/7.2/ cannot be found?

Answer (score 0):

Found it after using terminal to search for a specific file:

```
find / -name "temlatefilename*" -print
```

Version 7.2 locates the Template files at:

```
~/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/7.2/config/Templates/
```